# Python 2.7 on Mac OSX. Corrupt module of framework

Tags: python, macos

I'm learning python and made a program on Mac OSX El Capitan and the code was working fine but randomly it started givving me errors without me changing anything in the code. I keep getting this Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "time.py", line 2, in <module>
    from lxml import html
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.6.4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .. import etree
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 4, in init lxml.etree (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:218282)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 8, in <module>
    import struct, sys, time, os
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/time.py", line 2, in <module>
    from lxml import html
ImportError: cannot import name html
```

I have everything installed including:

```
from lxml import html
from tabulate import tabulate
import requests
import datetime
```

I'm not sure what happened. I even used Homebrew to uninstall and reinstall python2.7 and still getting the same error.

What is going on?

Comment: Do you have a file called `lxml` on your desktop?

Comment: The `time.py` on your desktop may be interfering with the Python standard library `time` as well.

Comment: type `which python` in terminl to make sure you're using brew installed python. From the looks of it, you're using system installed python.

Comment: which python /usr/local/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I changed the name of the file to t.py like ShreevatsaR said. Also put the file on Desktop, and I have everything installed through pip. For some odd reason I installed requests and tabulate manually by downloading them and running setup.py and vuala!! It worked!

user3543300, maybe the pip was installing it on the homebrew because it acted like they're not there. When I ran which python it gave me this:
/usr/local/bin/python